# Should I explicitly install Netty on my server?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I want to run my Play App in a production server, I know that it's kinda bundled with Netty server. I'm a noob here, but is there any performance enhancement if I explicitly install Netty on my server ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't have to, however it is recommended by `Play!` team to setup a full-blown front-end HTTP sever anyway. In project I work with, `Play!` app is backed by `nginx` http server. It helps handling https, assets etc. More details how to setup front-end server [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.3/HTTPServer).

Comment: Doesn't Netty handle http too ?? I'm a noob here.. Please elaborate.. ^^

Comment: Netty, as @biesior explained is used internally by `Play!`, thus handles HTTP, async I/O and supports long-term requests.

Comment: Can you comment on how big is the improvement after installing Nginx? Maybe like number of response or concurrent user..

Comment: It does not improve concurrency nor number of responses as it is an extra layer between client and `Play!` app. It makes your life easier by introducing modules http://wiki.nginx.org/Modules . Adding, lets say, support of GZip responses in `Play!` requires some development, which I cannot afford right now, however `nginx` has a module which can be installed quickly with no issues. In my project I use it for flip-switching and load balancing mostly.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need, it's built-in the Play app.

Take a look into the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionConfiguration) for details about configuration it.